# git push --mirror automatically adding links to incorrect work items

Tags: git, azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I have cloned a repo from a TFS instance using git clone --bare [url].
After cloning the repo to local machine, I am pushing it to Azure DevOps using git push --mirror [url].

After the repository was successfully cloned in Azure DevOps, some commit links were added to some of the totally unrelated workitems in a different project.

Is there a reason why commit links are incorrectly added to random workitems ?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably annotations in the commits like `#1234`. That's how Git commits are linked to work items. You can rewrite those commits and change the commit messages, but that will cause the SHA hashes of the commits to change, which could be disruptive to anyone actively working on the repo.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way I can avoid automatic linking of Git commits when mirroring repository ?